# c# format objects for querystring

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, rest

I am writing some extensions to a shop flow where I need to make some calls to a REST service. Because of many places from which I need to call this, I need to do it from c# (this being said for the suggestions to use jquery or other ideas that involves code going to the frontend).

Short version: I need to format an array of objects and pass it along for a GET request.

Long version: Here is a bit of jQuery to examplify

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var url = "https://somerandomserver.com/do/stuff";

    var data = {
    ip : "1.2.3.4",
    goods : [
        {
            CategoryId: 10,
            CategoryPath: "hvitevarer/kjøl og frys/innbygning",
            Name: "gammelmandstelefon",
            Height: 10,
            Weight: 1,
            Width: 50,
            Depth: 18
        },
        {
            CategoryId: 11,
            CategoryPath: "hvitevarer/kjøl og frys/innbygning",
            Name: "nymandstelefon",
            Height: 10,
            Weight: 1,
            Width: 50,
            Depth: 18
        }
    ]
};

var headers = { 'api-key' : 'api-key' };
$.ajax({
url : url,
headers : headers,
type : 'get',
data : data,
}).done(function( result ){
console.log( result.data );
});});
</script>
```

What I would like is to format my business objects so that I can pass it along to the HttpWebRequest without having to manually build every single part of the querystring.

Something along the lines of this (only that it would be actualy working):

```
    public static string GetTheString(string ip, AvailabilityGoods[] goods){
var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(goods);
return string.Format("/do/stuff?ip={0}&goods={1}", ip, HttpUtility.UrlEncode(json));
}
```

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `HTTP/GET` request cannot contain a *request body*. Since they're meant to be used to get content, you won't *send content* to *get content*. I wouldn't use the *query string* in your case.

If you need to send data, you either need the following verbs:

- `HTTP/POST`, if you need to create a new object in the server-side.
- `HTTP/PUT`, if you need to update an existing object in the server-side.

In the other hand, if you want to format a JavaScript object as JSON, you need to use the built-in `JSON` object and its `JSON.stringify(...)` function, or provide the right content type (i.e. `application/json`) to `jQuery.ajax` function.

Comment: Problem is that I'm calling a 3rd party service so I'm not the one defining the functions. However, if you note the jQuery, it contains an array which is passed to the querystring at the time the GET is made.

For some reason, the c# function didn't work at first - when I ran the jQuery and subsequently using Fiddler (see my comment below), the code worked so I'm thinking it may be related to something else entirely (could be SSL certificate related). Anyways, I had to create the call in c# and not using jQuery was was noted.

Comment: @Tony Yeah, I noted that you passed the object to jQuery and this turns the data into query string parameters. That's why I tried to explain you that you shouldn't be using GET request this way. If it's a third-party service... It seems like it's not that well designed... Or who knows, I should know what's the whole service... Anyway you can't pretend that with that few info in your question anyone could fix the issue at all...

Comment: If you run that script and check it in fiddler, you will notice that the data{} is formatted for the querystring. Whether or not it is good code practice could be argued, but it doesn't change the fact that it is what I have to work with :)

Comment: @Tony Yeah! Absolutely. I mean, I tried to give you a hint for you... If you can't change the service.....

Answer (score 0):

Well, seem that going for a smoke and then returning to show this to a colleague was all that was required: While demonstrating the code, it worked: No more 502 returned from the service but a nice 200 instead.